# Jetty 8 Logging Verbosity Level

Tags: logging, jetty

I'm trying to change jetty server verbosity level from Info to Debug.

This is the `jetty-logging.xml` file currently set:

```xml
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

<New id="ServerLog" class="java.io.PrintStream">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.RolloverFileOutputStream">
      <Arg><Property name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.stderrout.log</Arg>
      <Arg type="boolean">false</Arg>
      <Arg type="int">90</Arg>
      <Arg><Call class="java.util.TimeZone" name="getTimeZone"><Arg>GMT</Arg></Call></Arg>
      <Get id="ServerLogName" name="datedFilename"/>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</New>

<!--     
<Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log" name="info"><Arg>Redirecting stderr/stdout to <Ref id="ServerLogName"/></Arg></Call> -->
<Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log" name="info"><Arg>Redirecting stderr/stdout to <Ref id="ServerLogName"/></Arg></Call>

<Call class="java.lang.System" name="setErr"><Arg><Ref id="ServerLog"/></Arg></Call>
<Call class="java.lang.System" name="setOut"><Arg><Ref id="ServerLog"/></Arg></Call>

</Configure>
```

How can it be done?

Comment: [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), consider upgrading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetty 8 was a transition period for logging controls.

It wasn't until very late in the release cycle that this was even possible.

The file `etc/jetty-logging.xml` has absolutely nothing to do with the logging layer, it's merely a convenience technique to capture the logging layer output and redirect it to a file.

> Jetty was started in 1995, and its logging layer predates all other java logging libraries and techniques by at least 5 years!

To control how / what is emitted by the logging layer to STDERR you need to manipulate that layer, namely the `StdErrLog` implementation.

This type of manipulation is partially available (in Jetty 8) via system properties.

Try using the `-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG` System property on your Java VM that started Jetty.

If you see no change in logging level, then your Jetty is too old for that functionality.  You'll either need to upgrade or attempt to configure Jetty to use `Slf4jLog` instead of `StdErrLog`, and then just configure logging everything using `slf4j` techniques (be sure you disable `etc/jetty-logging.xml` if you use `slf4j`! otherwise you'll have a bad week)